The value got from onChange is always the old one
I created an image view like the ChildView below.
But when I update the image, it has some strange behavior.
The value is still the old one after the closure of the old onChange closure being called in this case. The url always has an one round delay.
But when I use the onChange in the content view, the url is up to date again in the block.
How does this onChange work?
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var url:URL? = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "image1", withExtension: "jpeg")
    let alt = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "image1", withExtension: "jpeg")
    let alt1 = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "image2", withExtension: "PNG")
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Change Image") {
                url == alt1 ? (url = alt) : (url = alt1)
            }
            Text("url : \(url?.lastPathComponent ?? "nil")")
            ChildView(url: url)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
struct ChildView: View {
    var url:URL?
    @State var image: UIImage? = nil
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            if let image = image {
                Image(uiImage: image)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
            }
        }
/*
        .task(id:url) {
            loadImage() //works fine.
        }
*/
        .onAppear{
            loadImage()
        }
        .onChange(of: url) { value in
            print("old OnChange \(url?.lastPathComponent) \(value?.lastPathComponent)")
            // "url: old, value: new" <--------- very strange here.
            loadImage()
        }
        .onChange(of:url) { old, new in //<--------- works fine, but only available in iOS 17.
        }
    }
    func loadImage() {
        if let url = url {
            image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: url.path)
        }
    }
}


You are using the old (now deprecated) version of .onChange, because you need to support iOS versions before iOS 17.
The documentation to the old version includes a note:

This modifier’s closure captures values that represent the state before the change. The new modifiers capture values that correspond to the new state. The new behavior makes it easier to perform updates that rely on values other than the one that caused the modifier’s closure to run.

So when your closure is run, the value of url is still the old one. You are calling loadImage from inside the closure, which therefore loads the old image.
To fix, try adding a parameter to loadImage:
func loadImage(url: URL?) {
    // ... implementation as before
}

Now supply the URL to load when calling the function. In the case of the call in the .onChange closure, this means passing value
.onAppear{
    loadImage(url: url) //  pass the current URL value
}
.onChange(of: url) { value in
    loadImage(url: value) //  pass the new URL value
}


As I thinking, You get old value of url in ChildView because onChange closure in ChildView is not recreate when url update. If you change url to @Binding or add .id() modifer to ChildView, you will get new value of url in onChange closure.
struct ChildView: View {
    //@Binding var url:URL? //<- add this works
    var url:URL?
    @State var image: UIImage? = nil
    var body: some View {
        ...
        //.id(url) //<- add this not works
        .onChange(of: url) { value in
            print("old OnChange \(url?.lastPathComponent) \(value?.lastPathComponent)")
            // "url: old, value: new" <--------- very strange here.
            loadImage()
        }
        //.id(url) //<- add this works
        .onChange(of:url) { old, new in //<--------- works fine, but only available in iOS 17.
        }
    }
}


I know, this new onChange works fine, but it's only available on iOS 17, so I have to use the old one.

@Perry It could be useful to edit the question and add this information inside of it

There is an issue with your code. Actually, you don't have to call loadImage so many times like this. Because url is a @State, ChildView will automatically reload itself:
struct ChildView: View {
    var url: URL?
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let url {
                Image(uiImage: UIImage(contentsOfFile: url.path)!)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: url) { value in
            //Will print out as expected
            print("old OnChange \(url?.lastPathComponent) \(value?.lastPathComponent)")
        }
    }
}

